# C# BigInteger.ModPow to negative exponent

Tags: c#, biginteger

I want to ModPow to negative exponent, does anyone have any idea how to make it?

Comment: I don't see as how that would yield a meaningful result. 8 ^ -1, for example, is 0.125. For that matter for any positive integer n, n ^ negative anything yields a result between zero and one. Taking the ( > 0 ) integer modulus of a number between zero and one yields that same number. Then there's the whole integer truncation thing that @Nathan C points out.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to perform ModPow with a negative exponent because that could result in a non-integer value.

As an alternate, you can use the Math.Pow function, which deals with doubles.

You can find details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)

**NOTE ABOUT MOD:**

MOD really only applies to integers. As soon as you use a negative exponent, you leave the world of integers. If you really insist on maintaining the MOD, you could do something like:

```
var result = (int)(Math.Floor(Math.Pow(x, exp))) % modulus;
```

Though I believe that would always result in a value of 0 for all values of x > 1